# After adding log4j property in ignite default config file, service not able to start

Tags: log4j, ignite

I'm trying to enable Log4j logger by using the gridLogger property in the config file like below:

```
<bean id="grid.cfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration"/>
<property name="gridLogger">
<bean class="org.apache.ignite.logger.log4j.Log4JLogger">
<constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="config/ignite-log4j.xml"/>
</bean>
</property>
```

But when starting the ignite.sh it is giving below error as it is not able to read the property parameter.

```
[root@ignite1 ~]# /usr/apache-ignite-2.7.6-bin/bin/ignite.sh
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.ignite.internal.util.GridUnsafe$2 (file:/usr/apache-ignite-2.7.6-bin/libs/ignite-core-2.7.6.jar) to field java.nio.Buffer.address
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.ignite.internal.util.GridUnsafe$2
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Failed to instantiate Spring XML application context [springUrl=file:/usr/apache-ignite-2.7.6-bin/config/default-config.xml, err=Line 29 in XML document from URL [file:/usr/apache-ignite-2.7.6-bin/config/default-config.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 29; columnNumber: 33; cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element '{"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":property}'. One of '{"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":import, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":alias, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":bean, WC[##other:"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"], "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":beans}' is expected.]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.convertException(IgniteUtils.java:1029)
        at org.apache.ignite.Ignition.start(Ignition.java:351)
        at org.apache.ignite.startup.cmdline.CommandLineStartup.main(CommandLineStartup.java:301)
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to instantiate Spring XML application context [springUrl=file:/usr/apache-ignite-2.7.6-bin/config/default-config.xml, err=Line 29 in XML document from URL [file:/usr/apache-ignite-2.7.6-bin/config/default-config.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 29; columnNumber: 33; cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element '{"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":property}'. One of '{"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":import, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":alias, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":bean, WC[##other:"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"], "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":beans}' is expected.]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.spring.IgniteSpringHelperImpl.applicationContext(IgniteSpringHelperImpl.java:392)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.spring.IgniteSpringHelperImpl.loadConfigurations(IgniteSpringHelperImpl.java:104)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.spring.IgniteSpringHelperImpl.loadConfigurations(IgniteSpringHelperImpl.java:98)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.loadConfigurations(IgnitionEx.java:751)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:952)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:861)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:731)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:700)
        at org.apache.ignite.Ignition.start(Ignition.java:348)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 29 in XML document from URL [file:/usr/apache-ignite-2.7.6-bin/config/default-config.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 29; columnNumber: 33; cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element '{"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":property}'. One of '{"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":import, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":alias, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":bean, WC[##other:"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"], "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":beans}' is expected.
        at
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error states that you have an invalid element property:

```
Invalid content was found starting with element '{"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":property}'
```

At the very first line, you occasionally have a closed `bean id="grid.cfg"` tag without a value.

Should be:

```
<beans ...
...
<bean id="grid.cfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
  <property name="gridLogger">
    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.logger.log4j.Log4JLogger">
      <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="config/ignite-log4j.xml"/>
    </bean>
  </property>
</bean>
</beans>
```

Also, do not forget to include the ignite-log4j.jar as a project dependency.
For maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
    <artifactId>ignite-log4j</artifactId>
    <version>${ignite.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks it worked but still the log is not generated as per my log4j.xml file. I am expecting logs to get generated on ignite.log so wondering what am I missing here ?

Comment: <appender name="FILE" class="org.apache.ignite.logger.log4j.Log4jRollingFileAppender">
        <param name="Threshold" value="DEBUG"/>
        <param name="File" value="${IGNITE_HOME}/work/log/ignite.log"/>
        <param name="Append" value="true"/>
        <param name="MaxFileSize" value="10MB"/>
        <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="10"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%d{ISO8601}][%-5p][%t][%c{1}] %m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>

Comment: Check what directory is configured for {IGNITE_HOME} env. Try to modify it to a well-known path or a plain file, say "myLogs.log" in that case you should find it inside a startup folder.

Comment: In log4j I've set the log file should be created as ignite.log but it is creating like this ignite-<some ID which I don't understand>.log e.g ignite-902e6165.log

Comment: Oh, I see. The thing is that Log4JLogger adds a nodeId shortcut to the provided filename. This could be useful if you run multiple nodes within the same working directory, I guess. Take a look at Log4jNodeIdFilePath.java for details. I am not sure at the moment whether this logic could be disabled.

Comment: Alex, I'm not a Java Expert hence can you help me on this

Comment: I would recommend you to create a separate question for that so that someone else could take a look into it.

Comment: Brief update: just use a standard  RollingFileAppender appender instead of Ignite's one - Log4jRollingFileAppender. In that case, your won't get a prefixed node instance in your file.