# Ignite Log4j not creating logs as ignite.log

Tags: log4j, ignite, gridgain

Configured Ignite Log4J module and logs are getting generated as ignite-uniqueid.log for each and every time. My requirement is to get the logs with single ignite.log only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, take a look at a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58942014/after-adding-log4j-property-in-ignite-default-config-file-service-not-able-to-s/58943438).

I found it useful to replace the Ignite's Log4jRollingFileAppender with the default RollingFileAppender that doesn't modify a destination filename.

More details:

Change Ignite configuration file:

```
...
    <property name="gridLogger">
       <bean class="org.apache.ignite.logger.log4j.Log4JLogger">
          <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="config/ignite-logging-log4j.xml"/>
       </bean>
    </property>
...
```

Made the following changes inside the ignite-logging-log4j.xml file settings. You can use the default one from the Ignite distribution zip as a placeholder. Change the FILE appender to this:

```
 <!--<appender name="FILE" class="org.apache.ignite.logger.log4j.Log4jRollingFileAppender">-->
    <appender name="FILE" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="Threshold" value="DEBUG"/>
        <param name="File" value="C:/Ignite/log/MyIgnite.log"/>
        <param name="Append" value="true"/>
        <param name="MaxFileSize" value="1KB"/>
        <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="10"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%d{ISO8601}][%-5p][%t][%c{1}] %m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>
```

Start Ignite instance.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Ignition.start("config/<your-ignite-config-filename>.xml");
}
```

After that, you should observe a bunch of ~1KB log files within your directory:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1  177 May  1 01:15 MyIgnite.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 1512 May  1 01:15 MyIgnite.log.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 1050 May  1 01:15 MyIgnite.log.10
-rw-r--r-- 1 1146 May  1 01:15 MyIgnite.log.2
-rw-r--r-- 1 1402 May  1 01:15 MyIgnite.log.3
```

Comment: Ooops! That was your question! Have you managed to try the last comment?

Comment: after replacing with default RollingFileAppender, ignite started to log to a single file. But it is logging all logs i.e INFO, DEBUG, WARN which causing the file size to a huge one and its not rotating the log file based on MaxFileSize. How to get rid all of these.

Comment: Hello, I haven't experienced that problem. My file gets rotated according to the settings. I updated the answer with fill configuration details. Please, let me know if your file is still not being rolled.

Comment: thanks for sharing the xml snippet. So, to enable the DEBUG logging for Ignite log I only need to set the "Threshold" parameter value to DEBUG, no other changes are required, correct?

Comment: I believe so. Just give it a try and check what would happen if WARN or ERROR level was specified.

Answer (score 0):

You should create your own `Log4JLogger` with XML configuration parameter and pass it to `IgniteConfiguration.setLogger`.

XML configuration file should be like [this one from Ignite source](https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/master/config/ignite-log4j.xml).

Comment: create own Log4JLogger with XML configuration parameter, does it mean standard Ignite Log4j config will not achieve my requirement? If so could you let me know procedure to create custom Log4JLogger with XML configuration parameter.

Comment: Please take a look at https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/logging#log4j